# Load an image from a url and submit it as form data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to submit an ajax request where one of the elements is a file without using a form (going into why requires a lot of explanation).  The question is, how can I load an image from a url and attach that to the ajax request.  So far I have the following:

```
var data = new FormData();
    data.append("widgetName", json.widgetJson.properties.widgetName);
    data.append("widgetJson", JSON.stringify(json.widgetJson));
    data.append("widgetId", widgetId);
    data.append("width", json.widgetJson.properties.width);
    data.append("height", json.widgetJson.properties.height);
    data.append("publish", true);
    data.append("updatePublishDate", 1);
    data.append("Upload", "Submit Query");
$.ajax({
    url: PROXY + 'http://xxx.xxx.com/xxx.php&userID=' + accountId + '&widgetId=' + widgetId,
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); //so far this works
        }
    });
```

So far this seems to be working, but now I need to attach an image to this, how would I go about that?

Cross browser compatibility is not a concern.  I only need to support chrome and maybe firefox, but not required.

Comment: Why can't you send the URL along and have your server side script fetch it?

Comment: Using a proxy, it's a cross domain script and that adds a layer of complication and this is just a util I'm building to solve a one off problem.  I might try that though, thanks.  Still not my first choice because I'd like to keep the implementation as simple and as portable as possible.  Also I'm not in control of the final destination.